# Как вывести товары с определенным id из сессии

Tags: php

Никогда раньше не работал с сессиями в php.
Есть массив который храниться в сессиях: `Array ( [0] => 555 [1] => 556 [2] => 557 [3] => 558 [4] => 559 [5] => 560)`
где `555`, `556`, `557` и тд - это `id` товара.

Товары хранятся в базе в таблице `tovv`

Не могу додуматься, как же вывести на страницу только те товары, `id` которых есть в массиве сессии.

Буду очень признателен за помощь!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если `$array` - это Ваш массив, то

```
$sqlStr = "SELECT * FROM tovv WHERE id IN (" . implode(", ", $array) . ")";
```

А дальше делаете запрос с этим синтаксисом

Comment: не подскажете, что я делаю не так? `$array = $_SESSION['idt'];

$catalog_tov = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tovv WHERE id = IN (" . implode(", ", $array) . ")");
 while ($tovar_c = mysql_fetch_assoc($catalog_tov))
  {

echo $tovar_c[name];
}` не выводит имя товара

Comment: Надо `WHERE id IN (" . implode(", ", $array) . ")"` - знак равно не нужен

Comment: Да, и не лишнее проверить, есть ли в массиве что-нить... `if (Count($array)>0) { [тут создавать и делать запрос] } `

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо. = это я нечаянно впер туда, и не заметил даже)) еще раз спасибо